# Создать n количество диагональных матриц (n×n)

Tags: java, матрицы

Как реализовать следующую программу:

1. Ввод с клавиатуры некоторого n
2. Выбор k (количество n): k от 1 до n (любые, также ввод с клавиатуры)
3. Создать n количество диагональных матриц (n×n), где на главной диагонали будут k.

Пример:

> 1. n=3
> 2. k1=2, k2=4, k3=7
> 3. Матрицы:
>
>    (1 матрица)
>
>    ```
>    200
>    020
>    002
>    ```
>
>    (2 матрица)
>
>    ```
>    400
>    040
>    004
>    ```
>
>    (3 матрица)
>
>    ```
>    700
>    070
>    007
>    ```

Comment: Дайте вопросу заголовок, отражающий суть. Тут 100500 вопросов про "программирование на языке Java".

Comment: С каким конкретно шагом возникли проблемы?

Comment: Создание n количество диагональных матриц n×n. Эти матрицы необходимы для дальнейших расчетов в программе. Буду обращаться к этим матрицам

Comment: С каким конкретно шагом проблема? С созданием матрицы, с запонением созданной матрицы данными, с созданием именно n матриц, с созданием матрицы размера n×n?

Answer (score 0):

Создать n матриц размером n на n можно следующим образом:

```
int[][][] matrices = new int[n][n][n];
```

Вам необходимо создать массив, который хранит N массивов размером NxN. Если вы знакомы с C++, то это то же самое, что и создать указатель на указатели, каждый из которых указывает на массив.
Приведу небольшой пример, как можно обращаться к элементам матриц

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // Перебор матриц

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { // Перебор строк матрицы i

            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) { // Перебор столбцов матрицы i
                // Ваш код здесь
                // Пр.: matrices[i][j][k] = 0
            }
        }
    }
```